# Access devices from iOS in same network but different subnet

Tags: ios, networking

I'm making a network analyzer tool in iOS, and it finds other devices in the same subnet (192.168.1.x) just fine using ping. 
But there are more switches and access points connected to the same router, that have different static ips like 10.100.100.x. I would like to ping those to see if they are still awake. I know their ip addresses, I just don't know if they are alive.

How can I ping/probe/nudge devices on the same network but different subnet? Is this possible at all from iOS? Can I perhaps reach them using their mac addresses?

Comment: Of course you can if your router will route the icmp packet to the host with static ip.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks. What if the router won't do that? Can my app broadcast a discovery packet to and get a response perhaps, or will that not work?

Comment: The router will do that, if not, how can that host receive ip packets from other subnet ?